# Remove menu item while using ResideMenu lib

Tags: java, android, xml, residemenu

How to remove or Disable Reside Menu item in Android

```
resideMenu.addMenuItem(itemQues,ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
```

I want to disable this item in second fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In `resideMenu` there is no function defined for Menu Activity:

```
resideMenu.removeMenuItem(itemQues,ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
```

For that you need to define it in **ResideMenu.java**,
just hold ctrl  + click on that code.

Then add the following code in **ResideMenu.java**:

```
  public void removeMenuItem(ResideMenuItem menuItem, int direction) {
    if (direction == DIRECTION_LEFT) {
        this.leftMenuItems.remove(menuItem);
        layoutLeftMenu.removeView(menuItem);
    } else {
        this.rightMenuItems.remove(menuItem);
        layoutRightMenu.removeView(menuItem);
    }
}
```